# Apache Superset / JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: apache-superset

I try to embed an Apache Superset chart on my web app as only-readable.

What did I do?

- I have add **PUBLIC_ROLE_LIKE_GAMMA = True** in superset_config.py and re-init app.
- In **Edit Chat Properties / Access** I added a custom user who has Public Role.
- In **Public Role**, I added permission to datasource.
- In **iFrame**, I appended **?standalone=true** on url.

I expected to see the chart appear on the app but I get a **JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data** error. I think it's an access right issue, but I don't understand where the error could come from.

[image: Image of the issue]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

Add property **SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None** to your **superset_config.py** configuration file and re-init your application.